# How does the following code snippet work?

Tags: python, eval, obd-ii

I am a novice in python and am going through an opensource project called pyOBD by Donour Sizemore for the ELM327(not really sure,could be aimed at more scantool devices).I can make out that the following is a method to convert a hex value to int.But how does it work? Specially the line with `eval` in it.

```
 def hex_to_int(str):
     i = eval("0x" + str, {}, {})
     return i
```

Comment: This is very, very bad code. Don't try to learn from it.

Comment: may be you can ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I actually cringed.  I don't cringe at code often.

Comment: This should have been `int(s, 16)` (and the parameter should have been called something other than `str`).

Comment: @OlehPrypin Could you please explain what makes this code so bad. I am only a beginner so can't evaluate it.

Comment: This code is bad for many reasons: 1) it overrides the `str` built-in inside the function.  2) the empty `{}`'s do absolutely nothing 3) `eval` will run any code you put in it (VERY dangerous) 4) the same thing can be accomplished by just doing `int(s, 16)`, where `s` is the string 5) it will blow up if you put in anything other than a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) runs a string as if it were Python code, and then outputs the result.

In this case, it runs something like `0xaf`, which is a way of specifying a hexadecimal literal, and outputs the resulting integer. Try typing `0xaf` into the Python interpreter, and you'll get an integer as the result.

`eval` is not safe to use on untrusted input. For example,

```
eval("0xa and __import__('os').remove('some/file/path')")
```

could delete a file on your system.

It would be better to use `ast.literal_eval` or `int`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("0xaf")
175
>>> int("af", 16)
175
```

Which are safe and produce the same result.

Comment: Oh okay..This does answer why the code is a no-no...but how is the hex value converted into an integer value?

Comment: @JaneLove Because Python recognizes `0xaf` as valid Python code, and runs it. Try typing that into the Python interpreter -- you'll get an integer as the output.